# What are the steps to apply filters to all my video clips in Corel Videostudio?

Tags: video, video-editor

I am able to drop each each filter to each of the clip.

But when I try - Select all clips - Drop a filter to the selections, it does not work as expected.  Instead the filter gets applied only to one clip.

Is there any other way to achieve what I am doing - Automatically fix exposure and colour levels to all clips?